# Sitecore: Filling my template content placeholder with subitems

Tags: sitecore

Having a template assigned to "Home", which contains different sublayouts/renderings for the header, menu (with links to subitems) and footer, and a "content" placeholder.
Structure looks as following:

```
 Home
   |--- SubItem1 (Linked to from my menu)
   |--- SubItem2 (Linked to from my menu)
   |--- SubItem3 (Linked to from my menu)
```

How would I go about filling the "content" placeholder of my "Home" template with the corrosponding subitem when navigating to it via my menu. (Note I want to maintain my home/main template for the subitems aswell)

Edit:
- I want to have a "sitewide" template (the one assigned to my Home), and have my subitem fit into the "content" placeholder of this template, when the subitem is navigated to.

Comment: Your question is not really clear to me, try to explain it a little further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you need the equivalent of an ASP.Net Master Page? Have you been on the Sitecore Developer Training since this is all covered? Are you Sitecore Certified and do you have access to [Sitecore Developer Network](http://sdn.sitecore.net)? If you haven't been on the training then I would suggest this is your first step.

I don't know of any articles off the top of my head that cover the basics step by step, you might want to read through:

[Learn Sitecore: Simple information site in Sitecore](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2010/03/Sitecore-simple-layout.aspx)

[Sitecore Presentation Reference](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Presentation%20Component%20Reference.aspx)

[Sitecore Presentation Cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Presentation%20Component%20Cookbook.aspx)

I'm struggling to explain all the steps that would be necessary to achieve what you want without knowing how much experience you have of Sitecore and related terminilogy but what you want to achieve is exactly what Sitecore is designed for.

Comment: No, havent been in dev. training, not certified, but yes, I have access to the SDN. I have skimmed most of the Presentation pdfs, and I have more or less solved the issue meself. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Great, good to hear. The training notes have good walkthroughs and details on the components in Sitecore so that is also a useful first resource if you have access to it.